# Is the Brownian motion $B_{t_i}$ independent from the increments $B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}$ (where $t_i <t_{k-1}<t_k$)

Tags: brownian-motion

Hi I know that by definition a Brownian motion $B_t$ has independent increments, i.e.

> $B_{t_1},B_{t_2}-B_{t_1},...,B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}$ are independent for all $0\le t_1 < t_2 <...< t_{k-1} < t_k$

However is the Brownian motion say $B_{t_i}$ independent of the increment  $B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}$? (Where $t_i < t_{k-1}$)

I'm just a little confused here as I don't view $B_{t_i}$ as an increment.

Comment: $B_{t_i}=B_{t_i}-B_0$

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thanks for the reply, I did think of this but I wasn't sure whether an increment had to be defined as $B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}$ i.e. I wasn't sure whether for example $B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-2}}$ was allowed as an increment, if you get what i'm trying say?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Indeed, $B_{t_i}, B_{t_{k-1}} - B_{t_i}, B_{t_k} - B_{t_{k-1}}$ are independent.

Comment: are overlapping increments independent i.e. are $B_{t_4}-B_{t_2}$ and $B_{t_3}-B_{t_1}$ independent?

Comment: No they are not independent.

Comment: One more question, for $0 < t_{k-1} < t_k < t_{k+1}$  since $B_{t_{k+1}}=B_{t_{k+1}} - B_0$  does that mean  $B_{t_{k}} - B_{t_{k-1}}$  is not independent from $B_{t_{k+1}}$  since they overlap?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks that helped clarify a lot